# Chrome extension to reduce the time by 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a simple extension where I would like to have two buttons (one being "Reduce Time" and other being "Reset Time").

I have created the manifest.json and other necessary files, including the html that contains the two buttons.

How should I code in the .js file so that I can achieve the following functionality:

1. On clicking the "Reduce Time", the system time should go back 10
   mins
2. On clicking the "Reset Time", the system time should revert
   back to original time.

My .js so far is thus:

```
var globalCount = 0;

function reduceTime(){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime()-600000);
    globalCount = globalCount + 1;
}

function resetTime(){
    var d = new Date();
    if(globalCount > 0)
    {
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (600000*globalCount));
    }   
}
```

But when I run the extension, and click on the "Reduce Time" button, I believe nothing happens as the date in the taskbar still shows the same value. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you know that Chrome extension's API has access to administrator-level features such as changing the system's date/time? I would be very surprised if that's possible.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's not possible via the APIs.

Comment: Why do you need to set the system time backward? Having the wrong time could cause a lot of problems with authentication setups.

Comment: I need to automate a script that would allow user to set the system time back, and then allow for some testing using the same.

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing what you're *asking* it to do. If you include a log statement after either of the setTime() calls, you'll find that `d` is indeed changed, just as setTime() is advertised to do. [Read more about setTime()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_settime.asp).

The code cannot do what you *want* it to do. JavaScript in a browser can't change the system clock. It would be all sorts of horror if it could.

Comment: Fair enough, I think it would be easier to do the same from a batch script of something alike.